# The side borders of the calendar do not appear

Tags: css, angular, fullcalendar, adminlte

I have an angular project version 7 (+), I'm using adminLTE 3, fullCalendar and I'm having trouble rendering the left and right edges of the calendar.

I am not able to manually adjust the calendar css to show the side borders.

What do I need to do to make the calendar borders render correctly?

[Here is the image of the project that I am using css adminLTE3 together with fullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQP2x.png)

Here, the link to the code that shares the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-with-adminlte3

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to look first its repo and issues section, since this is more related to a package.
https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some css rule in your custom stylesheet. Possibly in the `style.css` stylesheet. Here is the code.

```
.fc-view-container {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I played with the css file. After adding `border-style: solid` there was a border appearing on all the side of the calendar. If you only want the border to appears on left and right you can do:
`border-left: <sizeOfBorder> <typeOfBorder> <colorOfBorder>` and in the same way `border-right: <s> <t> <c>`
Also, try to change the `padding` value from 0 to -1 and it will extend the table fully to the side frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!